# How to install into CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

Using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/), I want to set the [`InstallDir`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#ainstalldir) to [CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx#CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA).

This might be something like

> C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

Unfortunately, [the variables/constants allowed in `InstallDir`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#varconstant) do not support the common app data folder.

So I tried:

```
System::Call 'shell32::SHGetSpecialFolderPath(i $HWNDPARENT, t .r1, i 0x23, i0)i.r0'
InstallDir "$1\MyProduct"
```

(`0x23` equals CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)

When compiling this, NSIS complains with the following error:

> Error: Can't add entry, no section or function is open!

**My question:**

How to set the installation directory to CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA?

Comment: Is my question that bad that it deserves a downvote?

Comment: Why are you attempting to install into the common appdata area? If you want something shared by all users, just go ahead and put it in Program Files.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is a setup for a local web application. I fear that it will not run correctly under the restricted Program Files location ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2096788/107625)).

Comment: And another downvote. Honestly: what is wrong with my question?

Comment: In that other question, the OP has observed that there are three virtual directories currently in IIS on their machine where the virtual directory is pointing within `Program Files`. And they're not stating that there's any issue with those VDirs. So I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. You "fear" that it won't work correctly under Program Files, but have you actually *tried* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SetShellVarContext` instruction changes some of the NSIS constants so that they point to the all-users version of the special path:

```
Function .onInit
SetShellVarContext all
StrCpy $InstDir $AppData
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8299478/107625), I found a workaround:

First, set `InstallDir` to something arbitrary:

```
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\MyProduct"
```

Next, use the `.onInit` function to change it:

```
Function .onInit
    System::Call 'shell32::SHGetSpecialFolderPath(i $HWNDPARENT, t .r1, i 0x23, i0)i.r0'
    StrCpy $InstDir "$1\MyProduct"
FunctionEnd
```